# Group policy works on Server not on Workstations

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have a Windows Server running Server2022.  I created a group policy to copy a file to the user's C: drive on login.
When I log on to the server this works like a charm, but it doesn't work when I log on to a workstation.  When I run gpresult, it shows me that the policy is applied. (as you can see)
****{Applied GPOshide
For CMDOW [{59EB365A-F68E-4680-95C1-11369AB9DB56}]****
I'm stumped.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Probably the "wait for network at startup" setting which has a different default setting on workstation.

Comment: since you basically hide anything, we can. mostly only guess and ask our glassball to support. Is there by chance possible to get more information, or is it classified as top secret? jokes aside, please read carefully [ask] rsop is mostly the first point and gpresult a second to start debugging

Answer (score 0):

cmdow program is mostly interpreted as malware by the antivirus/antimalware agents. PLs chk your antivirus/antimalware logs on the workstations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).